# How to make super constructor required in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like the IDE to inform me that I need to construct super constructor in inherited widget's constructor. Say for example if I have abstract class like below

```dart
abstract class BaseClass {
  final String name;

  BaseClass({
    @required String name,
  }) : this.name = name;
}
```

I want the child class to know that I need to implement the super constructor. The below code throws at runtime but how do I make sure that it throws in build time or IDE lets me know before build?

```dart
class ChildClass extends BaseClass{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a derived class neglects to explicitly invoke a base class constructor, it implicitly invokes the base class's default (unnamed) constructor with zero arguments.  You therefore have several options to get a build-time warning:

- Do not give the base class an unnamed constructor.  Make all base class constructors named.
- Make the unnamed base class constructor use one or more required positional parameters.
- Make the unnamed base class constructor use one or more required named parameters.  This requires enabling Dart's null safety features and using the new `required` keyword instead of `package:meta`'s `@required` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the doc [Dart lang tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors)

> Constructors aren’t inherited
>
> Subclasses don’t inherit constructors from their superclass. A subclass that declares no constructors has only the default (no argument, no name) constructor.

Therefore you have to call the super constructor in order to get the build time warning.

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
  ChildClass() : super(); // This will give you 'The parameter 'name' is required.'
}
```

But to get the warning when you try to instantiate it, you will need to add another required annotation anyway.

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
  ChildClass({@required name}) : super(name: name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 :

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  final String name;

  BaseClass(
    String name,
  ) : this.name = name;
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
  ChildClass() {}
}
```

**You will get a warning from IDE :**

> The superclass 'BaseClass' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.

**This means that you need to call the superclass's constructor in the ChildClass's constructor.**

Step 2 :

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
  ChildClass() : super('Shubham');
  
  get getName => name;
}
```

**Now we can test it making an instance of `ChildClass`.**

```
void main() {
 var child =  ChildClass();
  print('Name : ${child.getName}');
}
```

**Output :**

> Shubham